# Convert VBS Script to List WMI Class Names to Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi, powershell-3.0, classname

Basically I'd like to use Powershell to dump a list of all available classes in the `root\cimv2` namespace.  I have a vbscript which accomplishes the task:

```
Set objWMIService = _ 
   GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}root\cimv2")

Set colClasses = objWMIService.SubClassesOf

For Each objClass In colClasses
If Left(objClass.Path_.Class,6) = "Win32_" Then
   WScript.Echo objClass.Path_.Class
End If
Next
```

I've been able to get powershell to retrieve the list, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to `Write-Host` the names.  This is where I'm at now:

```
$WMIService = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -List
$aClasses = $WMIService.SubClassesOf
foreach ($Class in $aClasses) {
    Write-Host $Class.Path_.Class
}
```

Powershell dumps a long list of nothing, so I know it's enumerated something.  I've tried all sorts of `$Class.x` and haven't hit the magic one yet.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to:

```
$WMIService = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -List
$WMIService | where { $_.Name -like "Win32_*" } | foreach { $_.Name }
```

Will get you what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: That's it!  And now I see why it wasn't working the way I was doing it...  Powershell had already enumerated the classes and organized the data (duh, I did tell it to `-List`).  Thank you very much!